# How are java arrays really working

Tags: java, arrays, jvm, runtime, scjp

Can someone explain me how arrays really work in Java.

I was surprised by the following code:

```
        Object test = new Object[2][2];
        Object test2 = new Object[] {
                new Object[2],new Object[2]
        };
        Object test3 = new Object[2][];
        ((Object[])test3)[0] = new Object[2];
        ((Object[])test3)[1] = new Object[2];
        System.out.println(test instanceof Object[]);
        System.out.println(test instanceof Object[][]);
        System.out.println(test2 instanceof Object[]);
        System.out.println(test2 instanceof Object[][]);
        System.out.println(test3 instanceof Object[]);
        System.out.println(test3 instanceof Object[][]);
```

only test2 is not an instance of Object[][]

What is the distinction at runtime?

Edit: i see some answers.
Jon Skeet, please notice that i can do:

```
Object[] test4 = (Object [])test;
test4[0] = "blaaa";
test4[1] = "toto";
System.out.println(test4);
```

test instanceof Object[] returns true, and no exception is raised at runtime on the cast. According to the SCJP book of Sierra & Bates, test IS-A Object[][] but also a Object[]

But when trying to reassigning a new value with "test4[0] = "blaaa";", i get an exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)

So it seems at runtime, both test and test2 IS-A Object[], and both contains object arrays, but only one of them IS-A Object[][]

Comment: I added my own answer to that question. It's perhaps out of scope but it will helps people understand the differencies between generics collections and arrays for the compiler and the jvm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test2` refers to an array of two elements. Its type is just `Object[]` - so those elements can refer to *any* objects. In particular, you could write:

```
// Valid
Object[] foo = (Object[]) test2;
foo[0] = "hello";
```

whereas that *wouldn't* work for `test`:

```
// Invalid - test isn't just an Object[], it's an Object[][]
Object[] foo = (Object[]) test;
test[0] = "hello";
```

because the element type of the array that `test` refers to is `Object[]` rather than `Object`. The array "knows" that each element should be null or a reference to an `Object[]`, so the VM will prevent it from storing a string.

You can convert `test` to an `Object[]` in the same way that you can convert a `String[]` to an `Object[]` - that's called *array covariance*, and it was a mistake to allow it in my opinion. The VM has to check stores at execution time, as we've seen.

Comment: @Sebastien: My point is that the store will fail. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet **this is off topic (but from JAVA)**: Can you please explain me the difference between `setPreferredSize()` and `setSize()` and what does `pack()` do ?

Comment: @Suhail: You're right, that's completely off-topic, and would be better asked in a separate question.

Comment: @SebastienLorber: I see you've "unticked" this as the answer - is there something which is still unclear? Let me know if I can edit to clarify anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually as someone said it is clear but perhaps not enough for me thus i posted an out of scope answer to help people understand differencies between arrays and generic collections

Comment: that's true but i think it would have been great to have a comparison with arrays covariance and generics in collections. I ticked your answer back but don't worry you already have enough points :p

Answer (score 12):

Test2 is only declared to be an array of objects. The objects it contains happen to be arrays as well, but this is not declared. That is the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find any complete answer to my question to i'll do it...

After finishing the reading of SCJP book, it's a lot clearer to me. It was just treated on the generics chapter rather than arrays one. (Generics vs Arrays)
Jon Skeet answer is good but seems incomplete to me.

So you have to understand the differences with generics and arrays.

Generics are just a "compilation security". There is no check at runtime. This means, by the following trick, you CAN insert String objets into a Set

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
    addString(set,"test");
    for ( Object o : (Set)set ) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
    for ( Object o : set ) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

public static void addString(Set set,String s) {
    set.add(s);
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
test
1
2
ClassCastException
```

http://www.ideone.com/nOSQz

Note that the code compile (with a warning) and runs perfectly fine, until you use that set with a `Set<Integer>` reference because there is an implicit cast that tries to cast String to Integer...

This has been done this way because of many reasons (not all exposed on the book) like retrocompatibility, and the need to be able to call legacy code (non generic), while providing non generic collections.

If you don't call any legacy code but only generics code, you should not have any problem like that, your collection contains only what you want since the compiler handled it, and there is no need to do checks at runtime...

Since generics do not have checks at runtime and try to prevent inserting the wrong item in a collection, it is forbidden to cast a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`, or to call a `method(List<Animal>`) with a `List<Dog>` param, because this would mean you could insert a Cat in a `List<Dog>` by manipulating a `List<Animal>`...

---

Arrays do not work the same.

An array have, like Jon Skeet sais, type covariance.

So we can convert a Dog[] to an Animal[] since Dog is an animal.

Like for generics, Java want to try to avoid inserting Cats to a Dog array.
But because of covariance, it can't be done at compile time.
Like Jon Skeet, i agree this covariance is perhaps not a good idea, but it's java legacy...
So, in opposition to generics, arrays do have runtime check to prevent inserting cats to a dog array.

At runtime, the JVM knows what should be inserted in my arrays, while with generics it doesn't.

---

So, back to my initial question

```
Object test = new Object[2][2];
Object[] test2 = (Object [])test;
test2[0] = "blaaa";
test2[1] = "toto";
System.out.println(test2);
```

test (2D array) can be casted to test2 (1D array), but behind the scene it is still a 2D array, which is finally, a 1D array A1 that expects to be filled with other 1D arrays A2's which contains Objects.

That's why an ArrayStoreException is raised when in A1 (finally test2) i try to insert a String, which is finally an Object but not an Object[]

---

To conclude:

There may be a little confusion because of using 1D and 2D arrays that can be casted to 1D arrays, but it would be exactly the same for this code:

Arrays:

```
Dog[] dogs = new Dog[1];
dogs[0] = new Dog();
Animal[] animals = (Animal [])dogs;
animals[1] = new Cat();
```

This fails at runtime on the 4th line.
And there is no way you can insert a cat into a dog array.

And if we do the same with generics

```
Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<Dog>();
dogs.add( new Dog() );
Set<Animal> animals = (Set<Animal>) dogs;
animals.add( new Cat() );
```

This doesn't compile because of the 3rd line. 
But by using legacy generics code you CAN insert a cat to a dogs set.

Answer (score 1):

The object referenced by test2 is an Object[].

Instanceof is testing the type of the object referenced by test2, not the type of the array's contents.

The array's contents at runtime are Object[]s, which can fit into the Object[] because Object[]s are Objects.

Answer (score 0):

`test2` is something that you can put any `Object` into because it was created via `new Object[]`.  You can only put `Object[]`s into `test` and `test3` because they were created via a constructor that is stricter : `new Object[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `test2` as

```
Object test2 = new Object[];     // This is a plain array of Objects.
```